# Trouble with strptime() conversion of duration time string

Tags: python, parsing, duration, python-polars, rust-chrono

I have some duration type data (lap times) as `pl.Utf8` that fails to convert using `strptime`, whereas regular datetimes work as expected.

Minutes (before :) and Seconds (before .) are *always* padded to two digits, Milliseconds are *always* 3 digits.

Lap times are always < 2 min.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "lap_time": ["01:14.007", "00:53.040", "01:00.123"]
})

df = df.with_columns(
    [
        # pl.col('release_date').str.strptime(pl.Date, fmt="%B %d, %Y"), # works
        pl.col('lap_time').str.strptime(pl.Time, fmt="%M:%S.%3f").cast(pl.Duration), # fails
    ]
)
```

So I used the `chrono` format specifier definitions from https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/format/strftime/index.html which are used as per the `polars` docs of `strptime`

the second conversion (for `lap_time`) always fails, no matter whether I use `.%f`, `.%3f`, `%.3f`. Apparently, `strptime` doesn't allow creating a `pl.Duration` directly, so I tried with `pl.Time` but it fails with error:

```
ComputeError: strict conversion to dates failed, maybe set strict=False
```

but setting `strict=False` yields all `null` values for the whole Series.

Am I missing something or this some weird behavior on `chrono`'s or `python-polars` part?

Comment: I don't think you actually want to parse the duration to a *time* here - what if the duration exceeds 24 hours ?! Instead, you're looking for something like [pandas.to_timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html).

Comment: you're right i don't want that, it was just a crutch because `strptime` doesn't take a `pl.Duration` as input.  accepted answer figured out the culprit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### General case

In case you have *duration* that may exceed 24 hours, you can extract data (minutes, seconds and so on) from string using *regex* pattern. For example:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "time": ["+01:14.007", "100:20.000", "-05:00.000"]
})

df.with_columns(
    pl.col("time").str.extract_all(r"([+-]?\d+)")
    #                                /
    #                 you will get array of length 3
    #                 ["min", "sec", "ms"]
).with_columns(
    pl.duration(
        minutes=pl.col("time").arr.get(0),
        seconds=pl.col("time").arr.get(1),
        milliseconds=pl.col("time").arr.get(2)
    ).alias("time")
)
```

```
┌──────────────┐
│ time         │
│ ---          │
│ duration[ns] │
╞══════════════╡
│ 1m 14s 7ms   │
│ 1h 40m 20s   │
│ -5m          │
└──────────────┘
```

---

#### About `pl.Time`

To convert data to `pl.Time`, you need to specify hours as well. When you add `00` hours to your time, code will work:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({"str_time": ["01:14.007", "01:18.880"]})

df.with_columns(
    duration = (pl.lit("00:") + pl.col("str_time"))\
        .str.strptime(pl.Time, fmt="%T%.3f")\
        .cast(pl.Duration)
)
```

```
┌───────────┬──────────────┐
│ str_time  ┆ duration     │
│ ---       ┆ ---          │
│ str       ┆ duration[μs] │
╞═══════════╪══════════════╡
│ 01:14.007 ┆ 1m 14s 7ms   │
│ 01:18.880 ┆ 1m 18s 880ms │
└───────────┴──────────────┘
```

Comment: that's it, must've missed it in the docs.  
thank you, will update post with adapted solution

Comment: I should undo my upvote... This is all a hack. Does this solution work for `Duration`'s bigger than 24 hours? I think `pl.Time` cannot be bigger than 24 as it represents time since midnight. Also, the second method assumes that none of the times will be >=100 hours, hence not robust code. Better use `str.extract` with regex: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.str.extract.html

Comment: As expected both proposed solutions fail for the reasonable generalization:
`df = pl.DataFrame({"str_time": ["100:00.000", "-05:00.000"]})`
I hope you adapt your answer as this is exactly the type of StackOverflow answer that causes harm because it isn't robust. Also fails if you try to pass a duration of 30 hours like `30:00:00` or negative `-05:00:00`

Comment: Nice @glebcom - now it should work for this format - can't think of reasonable edge cases. A proper parser would still be better but that's beyond what one can expect from a SO answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Create your own parser - `strptime` works for DateTime stamps only, not for time deltas. The accepted answer is bad practice as it fails for reasonable inputs like durations of 80 minutes, or negative durations.

You can use [`pl.Series.str.extract()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.str.extract.html) to make your own regex parser and extract the values you want before passing them into the `Duration` constructor.

As far as I'm aware there is no "duration stamp" parser in Rust. Maybe good idea for a crate if anyone is reading this. Syntax could be similar to `strptime` but handle cases like: negative duration, non-wrapping for the most significant "digit"/subunit, in this case where it's a "minute duration stamp" you would wrap seconds at 60 but not minutes. Especially making sure that 61 remains 61.

Answer (score 0):

Code adapted from [glebcom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75654425/5446749):

```py
df = df.with_columns(
    [
        # pl.col('release_date').str.strptime(pl.Date, fmt="%B %d, %Y"), # works
        pl.duration(
            minutes=pl.col("lap_time").str.slice(0,2),
            seconds=pl.col("lap_time").str.slice(3,2),
            milliseconds=pl.col("lap_time").str.slice(6,3)
        ).alias('lap_time'),
    ]
)
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/75654140/3) to the question [Trouble with strptime() conversion of duration time string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75654140/trouble-with-strptime-conversion-of-duration-time-string) by the OP [Dorian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5986770/dorian) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>

Comment: Fails in both of these cases `100:00.000` (3 digit hours) or `-05:00:00` (negative)

Comment: true, but in my particular case that is no concern as all observed times are strictly two-digit minutes - so this answer is still useful.